# Adding multiple checkbox in drupal using cck

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I am trying to add multiple checkbox. My requirement is how can you travel the place with

1. Plane
2. Train
3. Bus
4. Ship

One can select all the four above options. For that I added a new field `Travel Details` , field type `Boolean` , Widget `Check boxes/radio buttons` . From [Drupal CCK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855981/checkbox-for-drupal-cck)

I made `Number of values` equal to `4` . But I am getting only two fields, also without their names ! How can I able to make this content type to behave like normal HTML checkboxes with their names ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **Boolean** field/value can only store `True` or `False`. What you need is a **List (text)** field with **Check boxes/radio buttons** widget.

Then put

```
Plane
Train
Bus
Ship
```

in the Allowed Values list.

You can set **Number of Values** to `4` but I'd set it to `Unlimited` just in case you add more allowed values and forget to update the number of values.